# time(); after 2038?

Tags: php, time, year2038

Will the php function `time();` be functional after the year 2038?

Comment: will there be internet in 2038th ?

Comment: If I knew how the world would work in 2038 I wouldn't be here answering questions...

Comment: Depends if you're running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of PHP

Comment: @Jon: You made me giggle, will sticks and stones work in 2038?

Comment: lol @alix lol maybe you are right i am worrying about it too early

Comment: @PeeHaa: Tell me the time so that I can make popcorns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, when the time comes PHP 42.1.3 will natively support 64-bit integers.

Comment: php version 42? PHP born about 10 years ago and now it's version 5 :) i don't think in 20 years it will reach version 42

Comment: @yes123 Whatever version we have by then, I do know that PHP6 will still be on the horizon somewhere.

Comment: i am young but i don't believe i will see php 6 while alive lol

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be.
But let me run that code in my VirtuaBox and changed the date as well in there.

you know it could be fun to try it out :)

Comment: You'll probably get a signed (negative) integer. Let me know how it goes! ;)

Comment: also I'm imagining that by that time, there will be a better language, new language or it might not be even called PHP anymore

Comment: What happened, did the world change?

Comment: @fedmich: No, RoR will be gone and PHP will still rule the world! NURV! :P

Comment: @fedmich If PHP's name changes, it'll probably change to "PHP", where the first P stands for "PHP", [of which the first P stands for "PHP"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym). Infinite recursion will crash the Internet.

Comment: Wait a moment. I Don't think you have to run a virtualbox to change the date in your os

Comment: I just execute it and I got -2138856280 ...
looks like our apps will break then :(

Comment: @yes123
I couldnt change the date of my computer/server as there's too many apps going on and processing some stuff;
so I could only execute codes like this via virtuabox.

Comment: Lol...
all I could say is that PHP Rocks!

Comment: You can fake the system time using [libfaketime](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/index.html). On Linux x86_64 with PHP 5.4.13, the value returned is not negative. `LD_PRELOAD=src/libfaketime.so.1 FAKETIME="31337-12-12 00:00:00" php -r 'echo time(),"\n";'` gives `48541007779`. Oh, but `date` seems to have issues interpreting `31337` though (`3508-03-16`). On the lucky side, `4242` works!