# PHP date() only from 1970 - 2038

Tags: php, date

First off, this is not a question about how to fix a problem because my date is outputting 1969.

This is a question about why time does not exist before 1970 or after 2038 when using `date()`.

I've tried seaching SO and Google but all that turns up is people getting errors when using `date()` incorrectly, resulting in the familiar output of `December 31, 1969 5:00 pm`

Does anyone know why it can't go before 1970? Should we stop using `date()` since it will be unusable after 2038?  What's the history on this? What's the work around for working with dates outside of this range?

Comment: number of seconds in a  int since midnight 1/1/1970, and I think its 2038...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Epoch fail! http://xkcd.com/376/

Comment: possible duplicate of [time(); after 2038?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826219/time-after-2038)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem

[image]

and look, [I'm in year 1653](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/97445.php)

Comment: Very nice, but trying to use `strtotime` on anything less than UTC won't output a negative.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @imoda: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 28 2011 08:24:40)

Comment: @imoda: I'm on amd64 Debian, that may be your problem. From documentation "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a **32-bit signed integer**) Additionally, **not all platforms support negative timestamps**, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch."

Answer (score 4):

This is explained on the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for `date()`:

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer).

The fact that you're getting December 31, 1969 means that you're likely supplying an odd `timestamp` parameter to `date()`, resulting in a date that isn't what you expect. Like @Mitch Wheat said in his comment, this relates to Unix time since it is relative from January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 3):

Compare the number 2^31 and the number of seconds between the two date.